# "puzzled why" vs "puzzled as to why"

Tags: phrases, word-usage

Is "puzzled why" correct as well? Is it just a choice of style? Or is there a difference in meaning? And if so, I'm curious (as to) what that difference is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Grammatical rules that apply to units larger than a word apply only to constituents.
"Puzzled why", however, is not a constituent, but rather a string taken from a sentence.

The psych predicate adjective *(be) puzzled* can take a number of complements, including tensed *that-* and *wh*-clauses

- *He was puzzled why she hadn't arrived yet.*
- *He was puzzled that she hadn't arrived yet.*

and a number of other constructions, often with prepositions

- *He was puzzled at Bill's expression.*
- *He's puzzled about the circus.*
- *He was puzzled at Mary's leaving early.*

There is also a Passive construction (like most psych predicates, which often come originally from passive participles), which allows a *by*-agent.

- *He was puzzled by Bill's expression. ~ Bill's expression puzzled him .*

As to the *as to*, that's just a longer (and optional) compound preposition governed by *puzzled*, like *at* and *about*.